# MSVC use additional include directories of referenced static library project

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, header-files, .lib

I have two projects in my C++ MSVC solution:

1. A static library project
2. A .exe project that has a reference to the Project #1 (the static library project)

- Project #1 has additional include directories, C:/addincdir .
- Project #1's header file, p1header.h includes the header hd.h from C:/addincdir.
- Project #2 includes p1header.h .

But when I build the solution, I get an error: Project #2 cannot open include file hd.h (cannot find/locate the header file.) I know the solution is to add C:/addincdir to Project #2's additional include directories.

But is there a way for MSVC to automatically add referenced project's additional include directories? Or is there some kind of macro like $(Project1additionalincludedirectories) that includes Project #1's additional include directories and I can add this variable to Project #2's additional include directories?

It just wouldn't be practical to copy-paste every additional include directory from Project #1 to Project #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no way to automatically add the folders.

(step 5 in [Walkthrough: Create and use a static library - Use the functionality from the static library in the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=vs-2019#UseLibInApp))

To include a header file (listed in the additional include folders) you need to use `<... >`

```
#include <header.h++>
```

Comment: So I should copy-paste all additional include directories from Project #1 to Project #2's additional include directories that are present in Project#1's header files and Project #2 includes?

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=vs-2019

Comment: Yes. You need to specify all the projects include paths.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an environmental variable such as using MORE_INC_DIR and set it to C:/addincdir1;C:/addincdir2;C:/addincdir3; and put $(MORE_INC_DIR) in the additional include directories of both projects.